# Where can I find the "Trap the Soul" 8th-level wizard spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

In the Wizard spell list, under level 8, there is a spell listed as *"Trap the Soul"*. However the spell can not be found in the subsequent spell descriptions.

Some people online are saying that the spell was folded into the "Imprisonment" spell; however, that spell is level 9 not 8, and is listed as a Warlock Spell, but not a Wizard spell.

Furthermore, the spell "imprisonment" doesn't trap any souls; it only imprisons the body of the target into either beneath the earth, chains, a prison on a demi-plane, by putting the person to sleep, or by shrinking the person to 1 inch and trapping their body in a gem.

Where can I find the spell description for *"Trap the Soul"*?

Answer (score 38):

Trap the soul should not be on the wizard spell list. [This was confirmed in a pair of tweets from Jeremy Crawford in 2014.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/508637715114373120) This is because Trap the Soul has indeed been merged into Imprisonment, along with many other spells:

> *Was trapped soul replaced with imprisonment? Is imprisonment supposed to be on the wizard spell list?*
>
> **Trap the soul shouldn't be on the spell list. But yes, it is correct that imprisonment is there.**
>
> *Is this because "trap the soul" is virtually the same as the minimus containment part of 'imprisonment in effects?*
>
> **The imprisonment spell has absorbed several other spells, including trap the soul.**

Answer (score 4):

According to [this reply by GladiusLegis on a post on Wizards of the Coast's old forums about this spell](https://web.archive.org/web/20151001033418/http://community.wizards.com/comment/51073736#comment-51073736):

> Trap the Soul was folded into the 9th-level Imprisonment, pretty much, as one of Imprisonment's forms is trapping someone in a tiny gem.

I have no idea on how concrete this is.

Comment: yes, I mentioned that in the question. But can you address my concerns that it's not on the wizard list, and is level 9 rather than 8?

Comment: Not until there is an official comment from wizards/an author. When the errata comes out we will know for sure. For now I suspect that it was updated after the wizard was written and Imprisonment should replace Trap The Soul (at the higher level). Again, need to wait for the errata.