# Delivering the soul of a teammate without killing them

Tags: dnd-5e, religions-and-deities, soul

I have a pact with the Raven queen. I have to deliver souls. My problem is that I now have to deliver the soul of a teammate. How can I solve this problem without killing them, like copying a soul or other such method?

I just want to fulfill my pact with the god, because otherwise I will lose all my magic. But I don't want to sacrifice a teammate to deliver a soul. How can I deliver the soul without killing the teammate?

Comment: I have voted to reopen now that edition is specified.  I suggest that you further edit your question to include your character's level.  Some of the answers will be heavily level dependent.   here is a related question, [related since it deals with souls in D&D 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/64585/22566)

Answer (score 5):

This is a difficult question to answer.

Mechanically, something like the Imprisonment spell referenced in [Is there any way to trap someone's soul?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70263/is-there-any-way-to-trap-someones-soul) would work and other ways to trap souls are also talked about.

> It shrinks the target to about one inch in height and it describes them as  being stuck inside of a gem.
>
> As to "not being able to escape" that will always depend on if this entity / person / demon has any friends who could free said entity. If you keep the gem / prison on your person, then you'd have to be overcome before this entity 
>   could be freed.
>
> You'd want the same hope of some chance of being freed if it were cast upon you, I suspect.

I suspect, without further details, that you already have a way to collect and deliver souls though since that is what the Raven Queen is asking for.

Beyond that, the short answer is: **No, you can't deliver their soul without killing them.**

However, it is really up to your DM and his interpretation of what would please the Raven Queen. It could be that something like having them sign a contract that on their death their soul is hers would be enough.

I seriously doubt trying to trick a goddess with a copy of a soul would work very well. You could possibly negotiate with her with other souls? Think of something like what Jack Sparrow does in the Pirates movies when he barters for his soul with Davey Jones.

However, if he expects you to literally reap the soul of a fellow party member, I suspect that he has some different and interesting plans. It sounds like your DM put you in this situation to cause some conflict in the party on purpose and is waiting to see how your character would react and what they would do when given this kind of choice.

**You may want to ask your DM what his intentions are.** If he expects this to be an interesting avenue to roleplaying opportunities and seeing how far your character will go to serve the Raven Queen, or possibly if he has spoken with the player of your target and intends you to go through with it in some fashion because the other player is ready to start a new character at the table.

Comment: *“However, if he expects…”* → I think it's also possible the other PC's player is collaborating with the DM to kill off the character in an entertaining fashion. It may be worth advising the asker to ask the DM out of game what's up with this divine command.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, Thanks! That's a good thought, so I worded the conclusion a little differently to include approaching the DM.

Comment: Note on the soul, from 9th level Astral Projection spell: *If the cord is cut—something that can happen only when an effect specifically states that it does — your soul and body are separated, killing you instantly* -  Not sure if you need further support in re soul/body, but you can add this if you like.